# Is there a Java equivalent/implementation of cracklib?

Tags: java, validation, passwords

I need to implement minimum password complexity checking in a Java web application (Spring/Hibernate).  It seems that on Linux I could use pam_cracklib, but is there a pure Java alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [PasswordCheck](http://justwild.us/examples/password/), a pure java password strengh checker. It's configurable so you can define what a strong password should look like, but documentation seems a bit lacking.

Comment: I saw that library, but it doesn't appear to be documented or have any kind of license.  Do you know where I might be able to find more information?

Comment: Looks like the site is down with no trace of where it went.

Answer (score 1):

Found via a a [Baeldung post](https://www.baeldung.com/registration-password-strength-and-rules), I've been liking [Passay](http://www.passay.org/) so far.

I haven't used cracklib directly, but this also seems to provide a configurable and extendable way to define the password validation rules that matter to you, and get clear error messages to present back to the user when those rules are violated.

Answer (score 0):

I also spotted the solinger version. It's unclear if it's a straight port and I'm interested to know what experience people have had with this one.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/solinger/